# Mixing Agda and Haskell code

Tags: lhs2tex

I'm preparing a presentation that contains Haskell code on some slides, and Agda on others. However, `lhs2TeX` dispatches globally on the input language, since it is specified by the command-line switch `--haskell` or `--agda`. Is there a way to mix the two?

Comment: I had a quick look at the lhs2tex manual online but I suspect that this is off topic here as it is all about configuring the tex generator to generate the right tex rather than asking about tex itself. Also most of us don't have lhs2tex, so you might be better asking on a Haskell list.